# Retrieving the latest records in each group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have one table, something like this:

Table news

```
Id   Name   Other_Columns
-------------------------
1    A       data 1
2    A       data 2
3    A       data 3
4    B       data 4
5    B       data 5
6    C       data 6
```

And I need to retrieve something like this

```
Group A
----------
data 1
data 2
data 3

Group B
----------
data 4
data 5

Group C
----------
data 6
```

Could someone help me with the MySql statement?

Comment: Yes, that's easy: `SELECT * FROM yourTable`. MySQL is not there to format the data for you. That's done in the presentation layer.

Comment: Really? I thought that I had seen something like this and with mysql

Comment: Just because you've seen it, doesn't mean it's best practice.

Comment: Hmm, okay, then I will send all data to array, and then I'll order them

Comment: Wait, didn't see your comment that you need 5 latest. You should have mentioned that earlier. Working on a solution, it's not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you actually want, but would this do?

```
select "Group A"
union all
select Other_Columns from news where name = "A"
union all
select "Group B"
union all
select Other_Columns from news where name = "B"
union all
select "Group C"
union all
select Other_Columns from news where name = "C"
```

Comment: I need to group all data by name and then get 5 latest entries from each group

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. The query will be like:

For Group A:

```
SELECT Other_Columns FROM news WHERE Name = 'A';
```

Place 'B' and 'C' in place of 'A', to get other Groups.

Comment: Yes, but I need to do this in one statement. And the names are not only 3 (A,B,C) they can be even 10 or more. ;)

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
select asdf.Name, asdf.Other_Columns from (
select
if(@prev != q.Name, @rownum:=1, @rownum:=@rownum+1) as rownumber, @prev:=q.Name, q.*
from (
select
Name,
Other_Columns
from
yourTable yt
, (select @rownum:=0, @prev:='') r
order by Id, Name, Other_Columns
)q
)asdf 
where asdf.rownumber <= 5
```

This will get you 5 latest. Formatting the data is done in presentation layer, like mentioned.

Comment: @Alex Glad I could help. "Best practice" on this site is, to accept answers by clicking the check left to the answer. This way others don't waste time since they see it's already solved and it's a great way to thank the answerer. :)